# How to use python to run a CLI program using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to open a CLI program with arguments and take a users input.
If i do it manually it looks like this

```
'/programfilepath' -i '/inputfile' -x asdf -o '/output path'
```

Because i need the user to be able to enter the input file i have it like this

```
import os
question1=input('What is the input file': )
os.system("'/programfilepath' -i question1 -x asdf -o '/output path'")
```

This is not working correctly after the user inputs the file and in terminal its giving me an output saying

```
sh1: 1: (string above with input file displayed correctly): not found
```

I know this is a formatting issue but im not sure of my exact issue thats causing issues.

Comment: use `os.system(f"'/programfilepath' -i {question1} -x asdf -o '/output path'")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.system` for precisely this reason. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

```
import subprocess

question1 = input('What is the input file': )
subprocess.run(['/programfilepath', '-i', question1, '-x', 'asdf', '-o', '/output path'])
```